# Why am I getting a 'Memory fault(coredump)' when I start the oracle listener?

Tags: unix, oracle, aix

This server (AIX ver 6) recently went out due a prolonged power outage. When I try to start the oracle listener I get this

> $ lsnrctl start
>   Memory fault(coredump)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious reason would be that the lsnrctl binary file, or one of the libraries it loads, got corrupted on disk when the power went out.  First run a file system check on all of your file systems, then reinstall the application.

Comment: It seems that for certain versions of Oracle this can also happen as the result of a corrupt `listener.ora` file.